# How to reload Variety wallpaper changer?

Tags: gnome-panel, startup-applications

I have installed Variety desktop wallpaper changer. Its a good app. But sometimes when I start Ubuntu and login to my account it fails to load. I try to manually start the app by clicking on variety icon, but doesnt work.

I tried alt+F2  and enter 'killall gnome-panel' but nothing seems to happen.

I checked in my startup applications window, variety is present there to start when Ubuntu starts.

but then why it does not start always? Restarting my pc is the only solution then.

Is there a way that I can reload Variety without logging off or restarting Ubuntu?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: And what does Variety outputs when running form the terminal?

Answer (score 0):

OK. Here is a method that works with me.

Do not autostart variety. Always launch it after you have started your DE (Desktop Environment). That has solved all problems for me.

In a session, if you have already started variety and it is causing any problems, start a terminal, type `variety`. It will give an error. The error will indicate the PID of the variety process already running.

Just do `kill -9 that PID.` and restart variety.

Let me know if this does not work.

Answer (score 0):

I'm the developer of Variety. Can you please report this as a bug on https://bugs.launchpad.net/variety/+filebug - I would like to see what goes wrong on your system with Variety when set to run on startup. It probably starts but fails to show its indicator icon for some reason.

To kill variety you can call `killall variety`.

Comment: well, removing old variety version and installing the latest one (0.4.11) seems to be working at this point. thanks a lot to the developer.